# Get wallet address when creating wallet with blockchain API

Tags: blockchain.info, api, address-generation

Using the API endpoint http://localhost:3000/api/v2/create I get this response:

```
{"guid":"58671a54-7d60-4319-8742-b06fb2a8d060","address":"xpub6CzAMijBVeK5qBxbXc2i4NyGbvr9wLRTJWf58f3mdv7Lb2eeo6Uz9UKq7ntTDdvfDgH6MhuuLJgCAWcto1BX9TA3wpaKU9vomML8MfvdZUD"}
```

It seems to be returning an extended public key rather than an address, how can I get the wallet address to accept payments?

Answer (score 0):

I've not used this myself, but it does look like the behaviour you're seeing is different to the [official documentation](https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_wallet_api) and the  [documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/blockchain/service-my-wallet-v3#api-documentation). You are getting the xpub of an HD Wallet in the response, instead of a standalone address. Which version did you install, and what does the documentation that come with it say? Are you passing any parameters to `create` that you didn't list in the question?